First and Last Move of the White King?
Here is a new retrograde chess puzzle! Depicted below is the final position of this game which White managed to end with a nice back-rank mate. In the course of this game, the white king went on an adventurous journey that somehow took him up to f7. How did that happen?
Can you determine the first and last move of the white king?


(12+12) FEN: 1nb1Q2k/1p1ppKpp/p1p5/8/8/5P1P/1PPPP1Pr/2B2BnR

Please provide your reasoning in your answer. Have fun solving this! :)

Here is my suggested solution

 White is missing RNNP. Black is missing QRR (Obviously P->R promotion +B captured at home)


 bNg1 is original, and must have arrived there from f3, as the rooks were already in place on g1 & h1. So bPfxgxh2xg1=R. Nf3 would check wKe1, so prior to opening of wK cage, wQd1 was captured by bN.


 So all missing White units are accounted for.


 Therefore wQe8 is promoted. bRa1 never escaped from cage, so wQ can't promote on d8. Must be promoted in north-west cage, so that takes at least 2 captures.


 But White's last move must have been a capture, to give Black a prior move.


 Last move was either Kf8xQf7 (as R couldn't move to f7 without illegal check) or Qd8xRe8 (as Q couldn't move to e8 without illegal check). But the second of these is impossible, because can't get wK from c7 to f7 with bR & bK in the north-east cage, and there is no unit available to shield. (bBf8 doesn't help because bRg8 & bKh8 is not achievable. wQf8 blocks Black from having any moves at all!)


 Therefore the first wK move was Ke1-d1, and the last was Kf8xQf7. There's a bunch more wK moves in the middle that are determined too!


 EDIT: Adding information about the capture balance. Black f-pawn captured wQR on g-file, wN on h2 & g1, promoting to Rg1. Black knight captured wQ on d1. White a-pawn captured bKR on b-file, bQR on a7, promoting to Qa8. White king as mentioned captured bQ on f7.


Exactly right, well done :)

@Nitrodon: I've added a sentence to capture your point, thank you.

Ok, I'm definitely missing something, but here are some thoughts. Tell me where I go wrong. :)

 1. The missing black pawn has to be the black rook in the corner, otherwise there's no way to get a rook there behind the pawns and the blocked bishops.


 2. That's the only black pawn missing, so the black knight in g1 must have moved there from f3 or h3, which are now occupied by white pawns. It can't have come from h3, because then there would be no space for the white and black rooks and the black knight. Therefore, it must have moved from f3.


 3. But at f3, the knight would check the white king, so the white king must have first stepped aside to d1, meaning the white queen must have been captured before that, and the final white queen at e8 must be promoted from the white a-pawn.


 4. In the final position, the last move has to have been made by the white king, since otherwise the white queen would have checked (or mated) the black king already before the move. The king can't have come from e6-g6 because of the pawns, so it must have come from f8.


 5. However, I don't know how the position before the last king move can be achieved, since black needs a move between the last white queen move and the final white king move, and there are no free pieces on the board that could have made that move.


 6. Best I can do is a final position with white Q at d8 instead (and white king moving e8-f7)


This is not that far off! 1.-3. mostly look pretty good, but after that you are missing a few possibilities :)

For step 4: rot13(Lbh'ir zvffrq gur cbffvovyvgl bs gur ynfg zbir orvat Dq8kr8#.)

@fljx, yep that did come to mind a bit after posting, but I couldn't get it to work (due to what Laska's answer now explains.)

Here is a full proof game of @Laska's solution. The key of this one is to

 take the f8-bishop early so black can castle and bring the h8-rook to b6 to be captured by the a-pawn so the queen can survive to deliver the final check.

Without further ado,

 1. Nc3 f5 2. Ne4 Nf6 3. Nc5 Ne4 4. Ne6 Ng5 5. Nxf8 f4 6. Ng6 a6 7. Ne5 O-O 8. a4 Rf6 9. a5 Rb6 10. axb6 Ra7 11. bxa7 c6 12. Ra3 Kh8 13. Rg3 fxg3 14. h3 Ne4 15. Nef3 Nc3 16. Nh2 Nxd1 17. a8=Q Ne3 18. Qa7 Nf5 19. Qa8 Nh4 20. Qa7 Nf3+ 21. Kd1 gxh2 22. Qa8 hxg1=R 23. Rh2 Rh1 24. Qa7 Ng1 25. Ke1 Qe8 26. f3 Qg6 27. Kf2 Qe8 28. Ke3 Qg6 29. Kd4 Qe6 30. Kc5 Kg8 31. Kb6 Kh8 32. Kc7 Kg8 33. Kd8 Kh8 34. Ke8 Kg8 35. Qb6 Kh8 36. Qd8 Qd5 37. Kf8 Qe6 38. Qe8 Qf7+ 39. Kxf7#


Thanks for this very nice. I don't think Black has to castle, but it might be a bit faster. Certainly bBf8 has to be clobbered to release bRh8 for sacrifice somewhere on the b-file

@Laska that's true, black castling isn't required, but it's certainly more elegant.

Yes, always nice to include a castle if one has the option. It's also more physical exercise because one has to shift 2 units instead of 1 :-)
